# Cannot read array in nested foreach after changing host

Tags: php, nested, nested-loops

I am quite new to php. I am experiencing problems with nested foreach loops. It seems I cannot read the data in $row, eg. $row['Tournament_NB_ID1']

I have tried looping through $arr_tournaments with a while loop before the foreach loops and there is data in the array. Also, I have tried changing the php version of the server, nothing seems to help. The code...

```
include 'variable.php';
include 'db_connect.php';

//Connect to database
db_connect();

$arr_tournaments = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_con'], "SELECT * FROM tournaments");
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . '<br>';
print_r ($arr_tournaments);

//$xml = simplexml_load_file("football.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_nordicbet_football); //Live file

foreach ($xml->children() as $game) {
    foreach ($arr_tournaments as $row) {

            if ($game->BreadCrumbs == $row['Tournament_NB_ID1']) {

                $id = $game['id'];
                $type = '1X2'; //Type of bet

                $season = $game->Season;
                $breadcrumbs = $game->Game->BreadCrumbs;
                $gamestarttime = $game->GameStartTime;

                echo 'Loop1';
                foreach ($game->OutcomeSet as $outcomeset) {
                    if ($outcomeset['type'] == $row['Tournament_NB_ID2']) {
                        echo 'loop2';
                        $outcomeset_type = $outcomeset['type'];
                        echo $outcomeset_type;
                        foreach ($outcomeset->Outcome as $outcome) {
                            switch ($outcome['name']) {
                                case '1':
                                    $outcome_odds1 = $outcome['odds'];
                                    $outcome_p1 = utf8_decode($outcome->Participant); //utf8_decode converts to iso ISO-8859-1 (has æøå)

                                case 'X':
                                    $outcome_oddsX = $outcome['odds'];

                                case '2':
                                    $outcome_odds2 = $outcome['odds'];
                                    $outcome_p2 = utf8_decode($outcome->Participant);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }


                $sql = "INSERT INTO ogames (Game_NB_ID, Participant1, Participant2, TournamentID, Odds_1, Odds_X, Odds_2, StartDateTime, GameType)
                       VALUES
                       ('$id', '$outcome_p1', '$outcome_p2', '$row[TournamentID]', '$outcome_odds1', '$outcome_oddsX', '$outcome_odds2', '$gamestarttime', '$type')
                       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                       Odds_1 = $outcome_odds1, Odds_X = $outcome_oddsX, Odds_2 = $outcome_odds2";
                // Does not update start time!!
                if (!mysqli_query($db_con, $sql)) {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db_con));
                }
                echo "1 record added" . "<br>";
            }

    }
}
mysqli_close($db_con);
```

Comment: did you check `$xml` for value as well?

Comment: `$arr_tournaments` is not an array, it's a `mysqli_result`. In PHP 5.4 it implements the `Traversable` interface, so it can be used in `foreach`. But I wonder if it works to repeat the loop; maybe it doesn't rewind the query each time.

Comment: Try using `mysqli_fetch_all()` so you fetch the data into a real array.

Comment: adding a mysqli_fetch_all() solved my problem! Your help is very much appreciated :-) Thanks!